# how to solve A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

i got this error when i run my code
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\hp.gradle\caches\jars-9\f596b4dd337df4b4bc8d9a578e73e7d7\gradle-7.1.2.jar.

Answer (score -1):

Go to this location : project/android/build.gradle

Replace your buildscript in build.gradle with below code.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work.